# FindMinimum pre-conditioning

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am wondering about what kind of pre-conditioning `FindMinimum` performs on the user specified function (to be minimized) before the actual minimization starts, and how this affects the convergence criteria?

From the Mathematica documentation I found the following convergence criteria.

$\|x_k-x^\ast\|\leq \max{(10^{-ag},\|x_k\|10^{-pg})}$ and $\|\nabla f(x_k)\|\leq 10^{-ag}$

Example code:

```
f[s_,x1_,x2_]:=s(Sin[x1]+Sin[x2]^2)
g[s_,x1_,x2_]=D[f[s,x1,x2],{{x1,x2}}];

sVal=1000;
sol=FindMinimum[f[sVal,x1,x2],{{x1,3},{x2,3}},Gradient:>(g[sVal,x1,x2]),PrecisionGoal->Infinity,AccuracyGoal->3,StepMonitor:>{Print[g[sVal,x1,x2]]}]

(*Out: "gradients" {{323.262,763.836},{42.7283,-495.664},{-169.037,102.658},{70.712,46.4036},{-2.11007,-16.4087},{-0.709215,1.65225},{0.0485022,-0.00759048}}
“final estimation {-1000,{x1->4.71244,x2->3.14159}}”*)
```

Looking at the gradients the convergence criteria it is never fulfilled using this scaling factor. I suspect that the gradients scale linearly with the scaling factor after a few runs with different scaling factors, and I would like to have this confirmed by someone with more experience in Mathematica than myself.

This shows that some pre-conditioning is performed on the problem before minimization starts. I have searched for an answer in the documentations without success, so if someone could help me I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.